# bootstrap button href does not work

Tags: button, href

Can someone please explain why my link does not work?

```js
<!-- Optional theme  this one is ok -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Get your Free Quote now!</button>
```

Answer (score 13):

The proper way to do it is use  but with class of buttons.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-primary">Get your Free Quote now!</a>
```

Fiddle Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/159899/

Comment: though the question is why it href does not work with buttons, this is a much better approach to solving the problem of not working href.

Answer (score 9):

You can do the following: It works.

```
<a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Get your Free Quote now!</button></a>
```

The design style of the button remains unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

Inline Javascript:

```
<button onclick="window.location='http://www.example.com';">Visit Page Now</button>
```

Defining a function in Javascript:

```
<script> function visitPage(){ window.location='http://www.example.com'; } </script> <button onclick="visitPage();">Visit Page Now</button>
```

or in Jquery

```
<button id="some_id">Visit Page Now</button> $('#some_id').click(function() { window.location='http://www.example.com'; });
```

In Bootstrap,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location='http://www.example.com';">Get your Free Quote now!</button>
```

Comment: This is a good answer.  The other answers with <a> tags technically work, but quite often different browsers will render those poorly in bootstrap.